# 'TypeError: Expected String or Unicode' when trying to convert json to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a json file:

```
['abc', 'bcd', 'chg', 'sdf', 'bvd', 'wer', 'ewe', 'sbc', 'osc']

>type(json_data)
>list
```

I am trying to convert it to a dataframe and add a column with an index:

```
df = pd.read_json(json_data)
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: Expected String or Unicode
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after? json_data is a list so there's no need to call read_json.

```
pd.DataFrame(json_data)
Out[715]: 
     0
0  abc
1  bcd
2  chg
3  sdf
4  bvd
5  wer
6  ewe
7  sbc
8  osc
```